# Searching XML Attributes to Parse XML Elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse XML elements based on certain XML attributes.  My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products updated="9/1/2017">
  <product name="o365">
    <addresslist type="IPv6">
      <address>2603:1020:200::682f:a1d8/128</address>
      <address>2603:1020:201::3c4/128</address>
      <address>2603:1030:603::6a/128</address>
      <address>2603:1030:603::72/128</address>
```

I can't get my code working, but I suspect there is a better way to approach this.  I want to get all **address** elements if the **product name="o365"** and the addresslist is **"type="IPv6"**.  My code is:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(r.text)

for node in tree.iter('product'):
    list = node.attrib.get('addresslist')
    address = node.attrib.get('address')
    if list and address:
        print '  %s :: %s' % (list, address)
    else:
        print name
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in elementtree, or do you have lxml installed as well?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('1.xml')

for x in tree.iter('product'):
if x.attrib.get('name') == 'o365':
    for y in tree.iter('addresslist'):
        if y.attrib.get('type') == 'IPv6':
            for z in tree.iter('address'):
                print z.text
```

with following output:

```
2603:1020:200::682f:a1d8/128 
2603:1020:201::3c4/128
2603:1030:603::6a/128
2603:1030:603::72/128
```

Comment: So here is the full URL I am parsing: https://support.content.office.net/en-us/static/O365IPAddresses.xml.  When I run your code, it shows more entries than just that IPv6 section?  (Which I would not expect it to)